# Apache Flink as a Service using REST API

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to create a web application with Apache Flink as a backend. Here flink need to talk to application layer(generally UI), so that the results from flink can be sent to frontend.

In Short i am looking for flink counterparts of projects like:

- Spark Job Server https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver
- Mist https://github.com/Hydrospheredata/mist

Comment: To my knowledge there isn't an equivalent to the Spark Job Server. At my company we had the idea to do that a few months ago and there was nothing like that. Another idea was the "REST source-sink operator" that we  tried to develop but never completed. Anyway, as I said, I don't think there's anything pre-baked. Usually the data is precomputed in function of the views, stored in MongoDB/ElasticSearch or other NoSQL db and then retrieved by the presentation layer. If your use case can't follow this path, I fear Flink's ecosystem is too immature

Comment: Have a look at the "control" stream concept - described here https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1289&v=_yHds9SvMfE - something worth exploring.

Answer (score 2):

The (deceptively titled) Monitoring Rest API detailed [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/rest_api.html#overview-of-jobs) seems like the way to go. Even though it says "Monitoring" it actually can upload, start, and stop jobs. In fact, based on the documentation it seems like it should do everything the web UI does.